# Routine to check delimiter in column

Tags: java, talend

I am getting my hands dirty with Java and writing a bit of code in Java for a Talend routine. The routine is to be used as a user-defined function in checking if the column data has a delimiter, if yes then reject that row, if not then pass that row.

```
public class CheckDelimiter {
   
    public static boolean checkDelimiter(String inputData,String delimiter) {
        if (inputData.contains(delimiter)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

When using it as a user-defined function it is giving error that boolean cannot be converted to string. While passing in Talend tmap, I am giving `CheckDelimiter.checkDelimiter(columname,"|")`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you check the output type of your data in output schema ? did you set it up as boolean ?

Comment: no , its string

Comment: did you try to set as string instead ? it should work if i understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

> *"... When using it as a user-defined function it is giving error that boolean cannot be converted to string. While passing in Talend tmap, I am giving `CheckDelimiter.checkDelimiter(columname,"|")`.
>
>
>
> What am I doing wrong here?"*

The provided code functions correctly.

The error you're describing happens when assigning a *boolean* value to a *String* resolve.

For example.

```java
String s = true;
```

```
java: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Considering your *checkDelimiter* method returns a *boolean* value, I imagine you're applying it incorrectly somewhere else.

There are a few things you can do to fix this.

Wrap the return value within a *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(boolean))* or *[Boolean#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#toString(boolean))* call.

```java
String s = String.valueOf(CheckDelimiter.checkDelimiter(columname,"|"));
```

```java
String s = Boolean.toString(CheckDelimiter.checkDelimiter(columname,"|"));
```

Alternately, utilize the *[Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html)* class as the return type, which provides a *toString* method.

```java
public static Boolean checkDelimiter(String inputData,String delimiter)
```

```java
String s = CheckDelimiter.checkDelimiter(columname,"|").toString();
```

Or finally, adjust the returning value of *checkDelimiter* to a *String*.

```java
public static String checkDelimiter(String inputData,String delimiter) {
    if (inputData.contains(delimiter)) {
        return String.valueOf(false);
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(true);
    }
}
```

On a final note, you can reduce the conditional statement to a single return.

```java
public static boolean checkDelimiter(String inputData,String delimiter) {
    return !inputData.contains(delimiter);
}
```

Comment: actually i want that when this condition satisfy if data contains "|" it should not pass and if data doesn't contain "|" the column should pass.

Comment: @dev_code, if I'm understanding correctly, that is what the code currently does.